# Visual Studio 2005 C++ debugger keeps stepping into disassembly view

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005

The Visual Studio 2005 C++ debugger keeps stepping into disassembly view when I "Step into" or "Step Over".  This is not something I want, so I have to keep right-clicking and "Go To Source Code".

It doesn't always do this - I think it gets confused when stepping between different projects in the same solution (static libs, and one console app) but all the projects have default settings and the "debug" configuration is selected, and cleaning and rebuilding doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an option under the menu Tools/Options/Debugging/General.
Make sure the "Show Disassembly If Source Is Not Available.” setting is turned off.

You can also look at [General, Debugging, Options Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85yzd16c(VS.80).aspx) on the MSDN site.

Comment: From what I understand in the link you put is that "Enable address-level debugging" also causes the disassembly window to pop.